# Woocommerce Customers API Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been trying to synchronize my WooCommerce customers with Laravel using this package, aiming to ensure seamless integration of products, orders, and customer data.

> composer require automattic/woocommerce

The package functions smoothly when retrieving Products or Orders.

**Here is the sample code.**

This code is returning an empty array from WooCommerce. The problem seems to be specific to customers, as it's not retrieving any data; only an empty array is returned.

```
$since_id = 0;
$url            =   $this->store['store_url'];
$consumer_key   =   $this->store['consumer_key'];
$consumer_secret=   $this->store['consumer_secret'];
$options        =   [ 'wp_api' => true, 'version' => 'wc/v3' ];
$woocommerce    =   new Client($url, $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $options);

$page = 1;
$per_page = 100; // Set a reasonable limit to avoid overloading
$limit = 10000;
$all_customers = [];
do {
    $args = [
        'per_page' => $per_page,
        'page' => $page,
    ];
    $customers = $woocommerce->get('customers', $args);
    $all_customers = array_merge($all_customers, $customers);
    // Check if there are more orders:
    $page++;
} while (count($customers) >= $per_page);
```

Here are the responses I'm receiving from WooCommerce:

```
Automattic\WooCommerce\Client {#6263 // Modules/WoocommerceSync/Jobs/Woocommerce/Sync/WoocommerceCustomer.php:66
  +http: 
Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient
\
HttpClient {#6262
    #ch: null
    #url: "http://localhost:10028/wp-json/wc/v3/"
    #consumerKey: "ck_6d519e5d047a33003acc6e9b2c9504c05569dc58"
    #consumerSecret: "cs_86fd82a32a6c7a347861d2f5f3ca26adfca105e2"
    #options: 
Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient
\
Options {#6261
      -options: array:2 [
        "wp_api" => true
        "version" => "wc/v3"
      ]
    }
    -customCurlOptions: []
    -request: null
    -response: null
    -responseHeaders: null
  }
}
[] // Modules/WoocommerceSync/Jobs/Woocommerce/Sync/WoocommerceCustomer.php:81
```

Comment: Hi, @SalmanKhanSohoo, can you edit your post to include the responses as code-formatted text instead of an image? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: @QuackE.Duck its updated

Answer (score 0):

Removed this check condition

$has_more = isset($orders['headers']['x-wp-totalpages']) && $page < $orders['headers']['x-wp-totalpages'];

Comment: @DanzonnTexhnologies there is no check $has_more but this $woocommerce->get('customers', $args) is returning an empty array.